# Bracket notation in a Map of Map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, kotlin-null-safety

In Kotlin it is possible to use bracket notation with a Map, so the following code:

```
  val mapOfMap: Map<String, Map<String, String>> = mapOf("Key1" to mapOf("Subkey1" to "Value1", "Subkey2" to "Value2"))
  println(mapOfMap["Key1"])
```

prints:

```
{Subkey1=Value1, Subkey2=Value2}
```

That's great. But why can't I do the following

```
println(mapOfMap["Key1"]["Subkey1"])
```

It causes a compilation error: ***Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Map?***

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapOfMap["Key1"]` returns `Map<String, String>?`, and `get` operator isn't specified for nullable `Map`. Therefore, the following code does not compile:

```
mapOfMap["Key1"]["Subkey1"]
```

You can make it compile by creating extension `get` `operator` function with nullable `Map` receiver:

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<K, V>?.get(key: K): V? = this?.get(key)
```

---

You can also create an extension `get` `operator` function for maps of maps:

```
operator fun <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, Map<K2, V>>.get(key1: K1, key2: K2): V? = get(key1)?.get(key2)
```

And use it this way:

```
mapOfMap["Key1", "Subkey1"]
```

Comment: I wonder why this extension get operator function with nullable Map receiver isn't defined in the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

Because `mapOfMap["Key1"]` could return null, since it cannot guess if the desired key is in the map or not. It's the same as calling `mapOfMap.get("Key1")`. The second map can be null, thus it cannot call another `.get()` on it. You can do this instead: `mapOfMap["Key1"]?.get("Subkey1")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to use only the bracket notation. Isn't it possible?

Comment: I think not this way. You can use this kind of aberration: `println((mapOfMap["Key1"] ?: mapOf())["Subkey1"])` but it's not exactly what you want. Perhaps you could experiment with a special kind of map (like EnumMap or something) where you can be sure there is a value for every key you can pass, but i'm not sure about it, it's only an idea :)